# In iText7, is there a "onCloseDocument" event like in iText5's PdfPageEvent?

Tags: itext7

In iText5, there's a "onCloseDocument" event under PdfPageEvent object.

But in iText7, if I want to do something after all pages are done just before the document is close, how should I do? Is a similar way like "onCloseDocument" event?

Comment: You are not able to do the custom logic before `document.close()` invocation, are you?

Comment: No, there is currently no such event.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, [have a look here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-7-handling-events-setting-viewer-preferences-and-writer-properties), which highlights some of the API changes to iText events.